# Client - server communication issues using openssl and certificates

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, client, ssl-certificate

The project i am working right now is to observe and analysis a communication between a server and a person (with wireshark) so we can decrypt it after that. becuase we have too many issues with server we made virtualize "server" in localhost. It's something we have tried before and worked. its not something grand nor speciel but it does not work at all now. when i try to verify my CA and cert, it has some errors. i have used the program called tinyCA2, and have used a toturial shown in this link, where it tells how to create a root CA, sub CA, sub Ca-chain, server certif and key.

http://theworldofapenguin.blogspot.com.au/2007/06/create-your-own-ca-with-tinyca2-part-1.html

after this is created i have open 2 terminals (in ubuntu) and coded this:

for the server

```
openssl s_server -cert d.santelices86@gmail.com-cert.pem -key d.santelices86@gmail.com-key.pem -WWW -cipher RC4-MD5 -no_ticket -accept 443 -CAfile sub-CA-cachain.pem-Verify 2
```

ones the server is up and running (which it dosnt) we have created a simple html-file (testssl.html) that contains some tekst and with a link to another simple html-file.
with openssl do we want the "client" to connect to the "server" and do a GET request.

```
openssl s_client -CAfile sub-CA-cachain.pem -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -cert d.santelices86@gmail.com-cert.pem -key d.santelices86@gmail.com-key.pem
```

ones this its done we should be able to see the communication between the client and server. 
but nothing happens, since they cant communicate. for that reason i have tried to verify the CA's by doing openssl verify cert.pem like below, and there are the results i get.

Root-CA:

```
mendez@ubuntu:~/Skrivebord/NETS_certificates$ openssl verify ROOTCA-cacert.pem

ROOTCA-cacert.pem: C = DK, L = Ballerup, O = DTU, CN = ROOTCA, emailAddress = d.santelices86@gmail.com
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

Sub-CA:

```
mendez@ubuntu:~/Skrivebord/NETS_certificates$ openssl verify sub-CA-cachain.pem
sub-CA-cachain.pem: C = DK, L = Ballerup, O = DTU, CN = ROOTCA, emailAddress = d.santelices86@gmail.com
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

webserver-cert:

```
mendez@ubuntu:~/Skrivebord/NETS_certificates$ openssl verify d.santelices86@gmail.com-cert.pem
d.santelices86@gmail.com-cert.pem: C = DK, L = Ballerup, O = DTU, CN = d.santelices86@gmail.com, emailAddress = d.santelices86@gmail.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

webserver key:

```
mendez@ubuntu:~/Skrivebord/NETS_certificates$ openssl verify d.santelices86@gmail.com-key.pem
unable to load certificate
140342585804448:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

what can i do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine the **Root-CA** and **Sub-CA** for  "-CAfile" command

```
cat Root-CA.pem  Sub-CA.pem > Combined.pem
openssl verify  -CAfile Combined.pem webserver-cert.pem
```